# CListCtrl class deprecated function - what are the alternative function that can be used

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, mfc

According to Microsoft Document

https://learn.microsoft.com/fi-fi/cpp/mfc/deprecated-ansi-apis?view=vs-2017

These are the list of functions that are already depreciated. I am using MFC CListCtrl class and there are bunch of function in this class which is already depreciated . The list for CListCtrl class deprecated function are as follows

```
AFX_ANSI_DEPRECATED void CancelEditLabel();

AFX_ANSI_DEPRECATED int EnableGroupView(BOOL fEnable);

AFX_ANSI_DEPRECATED int GetGroupInfo(int iGroupId,
    PLVGROUP pgrp) const;

AFX_ANSI_DEPRECATED void GetGroupMetrics(PLVGROUPMETRICS pGroupMetrics) const;

AFX_ANSI_DEPRECATED BOOL GetInsertMark(LPLVINSERTMARK lvim) const;

AFX_ANSI_DEPRECATED COLORREF GetInsertMarkColor() const;

AFX_ANSI_DEPRECATED int GetInsertMarkRect(LPRECT pRect) const;

AFX_ANSI_DEPRECATED COLORREF GetOutlineColor() const;

AFX_ANSI_DEPRECATED UINT GetSelectedColumn() const;

AFX_ANSI_DEPRECATED BOOL GetTileInfo(PLVTILEINFO pti) const;

AFX_ANSI_DEPRECATED BOOL GetTileViewInfo(PLVTILEVIEWINFO ptvi) const;

AFX_ANSI_DEPRECATED DWORD GetView() const;

AFX_ANSI_DEPRECATED BOOL HasGroup(int iGroupId) const;

AFX_ANSI_DEPRECATED int InsertGroup(int index,
    PLVGROUP pgrp);

AFX_ANSI_DEPRECATED void InsertGroupSorted(PLVINSERTGROUPSORTED pStructInsert);

AFX_ANSI_DEPRECATED int InsertMarkHitTest(LPPOINT pPoint,
    LPLVINSERTMARK lvim) const;

AFX_ANSI_DEPRECATED BOOL IsGroupViewEnabled() const;

AFX_ANSI_DEPRECATED void MoveGroup(int iGroupId,
    int toIndex);

AFX_ANSI_DEPRECATED void MoveItemToGroup(int idItemFrom,
    int idGroupTo);

AFX_ANSI_DEPRECATED void RemoveAllGroups();

AFX_ANSI_DEPRECATED int RemoveGroup(int iGroupId);

AFX_ANSI_DEPRECATED BOOL SetGroupInfo(int iGroupId,
    PLVGROUP pGroup);

AFX_ANSI_DEPRECATED void SetGroupMetrics(PLVGROUPMETRICS pGroupMetrics);

AFX_ANSI_DEPRECATED BOOL SetInfoTip(PLVSETINFOTIP plvInfoTip);

AFX_ANSI_DEPRECATED BOOL SetInsertMark(LPLVINSERTMARK lvim);

AFX_ANSI_DEPRECATED COLORREF SetInsertMarkColor(COLORREF color);

AFX_ANSI_DEPRECATED COLORREF SetOutlineColor(COLORREF color);

AFX_ANSI_DEPRECATED void SetSelectedColumn(int iCol);

AFX_ANSI_DEPRECATED BOOL SetTileInfo(PLVTILEINFO pti);

AFX_ANSI_DEPRECATED BOOL SetTileViewInfo(PLVTILEVIEWINFO ptvi);

AFX_ANSI_DEPRECATED DWORD SetView(int iView);

AFX_ANSI_DEPRECATED BOOL SortGroups(PFNLVGROUPCOMPARE _pfnGroupCompare,
    LPVOID _plv);
```

I am specifically using the **UINT GetSelectedColumn() const** function and I am getting impacted because of this.

Can somebody please recommend instead of using the above function is there any alternative function which I can use ? or is there any other approach I can take in order to resolve the problem. If there is any sample code you can recommend to tackle the problem that will be great. Just as an FYI, I am using Windows 10 ver OS and VS2015.

I will really appreciate if somebody can throw some light at the earliest.

Many Thanks - Yan

Answer (score 1):

From the Microsoft Docs page "[Deprecated ANSI APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/deprecated-ansi-apis?view=vs-2015)":

> The Microsoft Foundation Class (MFC) library is migrating toward
>   classes and methods that are based on the Unicode character set.
>   Consequently, the ANSI versions of several MFC methods are deprecated.
>   Use the Unicode versions of these methods in your future applications.

Compile your application for **Unicode** to get rid of the warning.

Project properties > General > Character Set: "Use Unicode Character Set"